# How to determine the true hierarchy of loaded JS files in a web page

Tags: javascript, extjs, google-chrome-devtools, aem, portal

`Background:` I am trying to make a web page work in a portal. Portal pulls a page from a site built on `Adobe AEM`, which uses `ext JS`, which adds on to the complexity. But the page of interest has a lot JS includes (~30), but portal strips any headers, nav bars or/and direct JS includes using script tags from the page and pulls only content.

`Issue:` So my strategy is to see what JS is required and include them directly in portal and it works in most cases. But in this specific case where in `Ext Js` is involved I am unable to accomplish the same.

I see a lot of JS files in the chrome dev tool, but unable to determine the correct hierarchy of files, so that I can manual include them on the portal side.

I tried to go by the `initiator` in the `dev tools` `network` tab, but a lot of files have the same initiator. So any smart ideas on how to determine the correct hierarchy? Or is there a fundamental issue that I am missing which will prohibit me from doing this?

P.S I can add more info/data if needed.

Comment: there _could_ be "a fundamental issue...", it depends. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you need an order of load ExtJS classes on a page and this help you to determinate right order to include JS files. 
You can use `Ext.Loader.history`. Just run it in console. 
And if you can inject [linq.js](https://linqjs.codeplex.com/) script, you can use my snippet that I use for ASP.NET MVC app

```
function replaceAll(replace, str) {
  return str.replace(/\./g, replace);
};
JSLINQ(Ext.Loader.history).Where(function(item){ return item.indexOf("HelloExt") !=-1 || item.indexOf("Ext.ux") !=-1; })
.Select(function(item){
if(item.indexOf("HelloExt") !=-1) {return "~/Scripts/"+replaceAll("/",item)+".js"}
else if(item.indexOf("Ext.ux") !=-1){
return "~/Scripts/helloext/extjs/examples/ux/"+replaceAll("/",item).replace("Ext/ux/","")+".js"
}}).ToArray()
```

Just replace `HelloExt` with name of your application and `~/Scripts/..` with correct path